# What causes the "procedure has not been executed or has no result" error and how to prevent it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, powerbuilder

Recently we are getting the "procedure has not been executed or has no result" across our PowerBuilder Application. This error is random, but is triggered in places where we have calls to Stored Procedures or some dynamic SQL queries. After each call to the procedure, we close the procedure in powerbuilder. We need to know the cause of this error because this is not caused on our environment, only in the production environment. Even better would be a way to resolve this issue.

The database is SQL Server. The exact error details are as follows:

ERROR Code: -1

ERROR Text: procedure has not been executed or has no result

Row Count:  0

Terminating application-

I am not even sure if the error is from Database or from Powerbuilder itself. The code is a simple call to a procedure. Here is some code that is causing this issue:

```
DECLARE setRequestStatus PROCEDURE FOR sRequestStatus
    // parameters here
USING SQLCA;

EXECUTE setRequestStatus;
FETCH setRequestStatus into :statusCode;
CLOSE sp_PfW_ERxSetRequestStatus;
RETURN statusCode
```

Do reply if you need any more details.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently the DB side must be generating an error which is propagated to your front end. Are you sure that its not a bug in the SQL Queries or Stored procedure and that it just occurs randomly?

Comment: You've provided no information that can be used to help track down the problem. Have you Googled the **exact** error message you're getting? You're asking us to speculate wildly on what might be an issue based on zero details about the issue, and that's not how this site works. Collect more information, [edit] your question to include it, and be much more specific about the problems and the circumstances around it happening.

Comment: So this just started 'out of the blue'?  Did you update/change something recently?

Comment: This started after the upgrade to the latest version of the application. But the code causing the error is unchanged.

Comment: Are you able to run the application via the development IDE, and in debug mode? If so do that and look at all of the SQLCA properties (global) you may find hints there. Also, you might be able to do a test build with application tracing turned on, in fact I think you can trace database activity as well, and have it written to a flat file. Another idea, if you know the data, try running the procedure from command prompt and see if you get errors, for example maybe the procedure expects at least one result, or only one result and it is not happening that way. Please follow up with more info

Comment: Oh, which version of PB did you upgrade to/from? Might be unicode issues, and you'd need to change functions to use Unicode/Ansi variety. P.S. This is a new user to SO, and if he/she doesn't have PB experience it might have seemed that his question contained the appropriate info... my point is... reconsider the negative votes on the question... we were all at the beginning once and I don't think this was a blatant case of laziness. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/PowerObject/conversations/topics/18504), the problem is an exception being raised by your stored procedure-- possibly due to transaction size. Follow the link to get more details.